# Magento paypal rounding issue with Discount

Tags: php, magento, paypal, rounding

I'm using magento 1.9.1.0, and  HUF curency that has no cents. 
If i don't use discount there is no  rounding error, but if i do use inside magento it calculates well:

[image: Good calculation and display]

But as soon as I try to use paypal to pay it i get the following error:

[image: Paypal error]
and I check the paypal button code i get this:

```
<img src="https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&amp;buttontype=ecshortcut&amp;locale=en_US&amp;ordertotal=5326.80&amp;pal=XXXXX" alt="Checkout with PayPal" title="Checkout with PayPal">
```

and the ordertotal is wrong! In the Order is 5327 while in the Paypal button is 5326.80. its 0.20 off. It should round up, with no decimals. And no  matter what i set, if a discount is used the rounding is all ways off!

The locale is wrong as well, even thought Hungary is set as a locale in magento.

How can I fix this rounding issues?

Comment: You question lacks clarity. I can tell you tried to make a good question, but you state, for instance: "and the ordertotal is wrong". That is vague at least. Better would be: "The total send to xxx is xxxx but xxx should have sent a total of xxxx because xxxx". Etc. Be very specific. Currently I can only see a rounding problem, is that it?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware edited for better clarity, and yes that's the Problem. HUF has no cents, just full numbers. yet with the discount  paypal recives 5326.80 instead of the correct value of 5327.

Answer (score 1):

Very often, some magento tax configurations don't play nicely with discount rules - particularly where PayPal is involved.

Within SYSTEM > CONFIGURATION check config under SALES -> TAX is set to 'apply customer tax AFTER discount', and not before. This fixed the issue for me.

Magento have a great page on their knowledge base explaining all the tax/discount configurations which can cause rounding errors: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-ce-18-ee-113-tax-calc

Comment: Sadly its already sets so and the problem still exists: http://i.imgur.com/GeAJuTu.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice(), and set the round to 0 decimal places.