# Magento rounding issue on Grand Total

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a strange issue on Magento Grand Total.

- I have a product of 99.99€ (inc. tax). The tax is 23% rate.
- I have created a Promo Code to have 25% discount on that product.
- I've set up the Tax Calculation Method based on the Row Total
- I've set up the Apply Customer Tax to be after discount
- I've set up the Apply Discount on Prices to be including tax.

The problem comes when I add the product and put a promo code, that created a change on 0.01€. Changing the precision to 4 or the rounding to 4 sometimes solves the issue but creates issues with payment gateways.

The cart page shows the following info:

```
Subtotal Excl Tax - 81.29

Subtotal Incl Tax - 99.99

Discount          - 25.00

Tax               - 14.02

Grand Total       - 74.98
```

The grand total should be 74.99€ (99.99€ from the product - 25.00€ from the discount).

Comment: The grand total shoudl be 74.99€ (99.99€ from the product - 25.00€ from the discount).

Comment: OK. Have you worked out which step introduces the inaccuracy? It's not going to be the subtraction - 99.99 - 25 won't have any rounding errors.

Comment: i belive its on the discount, it 24.9975...and it rounds to 25.00.
The tax seems to be right, considering the discount amount of 25.00.

Comment: Are you holding a value of 25.00€ as a decimal? I don't know how Magento recommends doing things, but this might be better held as 2500 euro cents, not 25 euros. In any case, you absolutely won't be the first person to encounter rounding issues in Magento - have you done a (thorough) search?

Comment: [Phew, plenty to look at](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=magento%20rounding)!

Comment: The 25.00€ are really 25% of the price of the product...99.99€...
I've looking a lot of links, and still cant find a solution for this.

Comment: I don't think that's answered my question. Are you holding 25€ as the value 25 or the value 2500? I don't have a lot of experience with price handling, but I've seen it said that holding fractional values (e.g. 74.99) will remove the accuracy from the third DP onwards, which will then feed inaccuracy into subsequent calculations.

Comment: The amount as far as my research led me is 25.00...at one point the rounding is right, rounding 24.9975 becomes 25.00, but somehow a wrong grand total is being displayed.

Comment: @halfer is right that Magento’s price rounding only seems to support up to two decimal places (hundredths) on price operations. The order that these calculations are applied absolutely can create small rounding issues, since they are applied in succession. You might try extending `Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice()` to support additional fractional granularity, but I don’t know what all the implications would be.

Comment: You should review [this answer, which links to the Magento documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28909775/1737136) on the subject.

Comment: @fantasticrice: I don't think the meaning of my earlier question was expressed well enough (twice) to be understood by the OP. I've no experience with Magento, but you seem to: do you think the OP could store their prices in euro cents rather than euros, thus giving another two decimal places of accuracy automatically? All they'd then need to do, I imagine, is to change the price rendering code and any interfacing with payment modules.

Comment: (Whether 2DP would be enough extra accuracy to avoid the rounding error, I don't know, but I think it would be worth a try).

Comment: @halfer - not that I am aware of, but since almost everything in Magento can be extended to work differently it’s not impossible theoretically. It would probably be pretty tricky to catch everything though. Magento has an [extensive doc on the subject](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-ce-18-ee-113-tax-calc) that I mentioned in a separate comment above.

Comment: well, i've changed the roundPrice, and that partially solves the issue. For the quantity of 1 it delivers the expected total, but when the quantity is 2 the total os wrong by 1 cent more, also changing the roundPrice to 4 decimal places causes problems with Payment Gateways.

Comment: ^ sure, that would be expected. Is there a mechanism in the payment gateway interface(s) to round back to 2dp? (The problem with the payment gateways _might_ be best as another question, linking to this one for reference).

Comment: @halfer, the comment was to everyone reading this. I will try a new approach...trying to change the way the grand total is calculated, i dont know if its possible but i will give it  a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento tax rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529580/magento-tax-rounding-issue)